# How to prevent repetition in the table when i search on value

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

when i search on a value in the table i get it but the problem here also when i search on a different value, the old result still in the table i want to refresh the table after search to just offer the target search in the tabla and preventing the repetation

here is an image for clarification
[open image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Yo46.jpg)

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String name = jTextField_name.getText().trim();
    String phone = jTextField_phone.getText().trim();

    String sql="";
    boolean flag = false;


        if(name.length() >=0 && phone.length() >0)
        {
            sql = " STAB.FIRST_NAME = '"+name+"' and STAB.PHONE = "+phone;
            flag = true;
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            grHndlr.searchStudentJtable(jTableStudentGrade , sql);
            //clear:
            jTextField_name.setText("");
            jTextField_phone.setText("");
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid data !!" , 
            "Failed" , 2);
        }
```

Update my code for the correct solution that helped me:

i used here vector

```
private void fillStudentGradeTable(Vector tableRows)
{
    model = (DefaultTableModel) jTableStudentGrade.getModel();
    model.setRowCount(0); //reset data:

    //get student data from DB //
    for(int i = 0; i < tableRows.size(); i++)
    {
       Vector row = (Vector)tableRows.elementAt(i);
       model.addRow(row);
    }
    jTableStudentGrade.setModel(model);
    jScrollPane.setViewportView(jTableStudentGrade);
}
```

then i called it in main code to refresh the table :

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String name = jTextField_name.getText().trim();
    String phone = jTextField_phone.getText().trim();

    String sql="";
    boolean flag = false;


        if(name.length() >=0 && phone.length() >0)
        {
            sql = " STAB.FIRST_NAME = '"+name+"' and STAB.PHONE = "+phone;
            flag = true;
        }

        if(flag)
        {
            //grHndlr.searchStudentJtable(jTableStudentGrade , sql);
            Vector tableRows = grHndlr.searchStudentJtable(sql);
            fillStudentGradeTable(tableRows);

            //clear:
            jTextField_name.setText("");
            jTextField_phone.setText("");

        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Enter valid data !!" , "Failed" , 2);
        }

}
```

Comment: out of the questions scope but `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--`, oops ([Using prepared statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), [SQL Injection Prevention Cheat Sheet - OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet))

Comment: Remove all the content from the table before adding new content to it, if you want only the latest data to appear

Comment: How i do it ?!l @Mark

Comment: What sort of table are you using? JTable?

Comment: am solve it and updated what i did but @Mark i want know how remove all the content from the table before adding new content to it . yes it was jTable

Comment: You've already added `setRowCount` which should remove content, so your code is good I'd say.

Comment: thank you man but i took some help